# Scraping saved comments and posts from Reddit

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, reddit

I am trying to scrape saved comments and posts on my reddit profile.
I have made a solution with selenium and python and it is providing results.
But it is utterly slow.

First it scrolls through the whole 1000 saved comments and posts(which takes around 41 mins)
and then it starts adding the links to a text file, which is also very slow. As it have to reload the data at top again.

All the posts and comments are dynamically loaded, also when new sections are loaded previous get hidden from the page.

A better approach would be to save the links right after they are loaded, but I am not sure how to approach that.

Any help is appreciated.

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from pyautogui import *
import os

sleepTime=5

loginUrl="https://www.reddit.com/login/"
savedUrl="https://www.reddit.com/user//saved"

username=''
password=''

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(loginUrl)

usernameField=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="loginUsername"]')
passwordField=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="loginPassword"]')

usernameField.send_keys(username)
passwordField.send_keys(password)

loginBtn=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div/main/div[1]/div/div[2]/form/fieldset[5]/button')
sleep(2)
loginBtn.click()

sleep(sleepTime)

driver.get(savedUrl)


sleep(8)

closeBtn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div/header/div/div[2]/button/i')
sleep(2)
closeBtn.click()

speed=-1000
sleep(sleepTime)
i=0

while i<500:
    scroll(speed)
    sleep(sleepTime)
    i=i+1

file2 = open(r"D:\python\links.txt","w+")

content=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@href, '/comments/')]")

for i in content:
    print(i.get_attribute('href'))
    file2.write(i.get_attribute('href')+'\n')

file2.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**, scrolling to the bottom, if you have too many post, you can build a for loop to do this. (1)

I'm using my profile https://www.reddit.com/user/9feisuijidechenghu, for example

```
scrollHeight = driver.execute_script('''return document.documentElement.scrollHeight''')
scroll_origin = ScrollOrigin.from_element(footer, 0, 0)
ActionChains(driver).scroll_from_origin(scroll_origin, 0, scrollHeight ).perform()
```

**Secondly**, loating these elements of the left post and comment by using the
xpath (2)
now using the **CLASS_NAME** to locate each block of post or comment
once locating each block, use for loop to get website(href) or other information.

```
leftpost = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, r"/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[5]")
eachpost = leftpost.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "scrollerItem")
for i in range(len(eachpost)):
    post = eachpost[i]
    comment = post.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "RichTextJSON-root").text
    ...
```

**Thirdly**, if you want to get the comment, you should use **.text**
let's define the html like this, from here [image: comment]
`<div class="_292iotee39Lmt0MkQZ2hPV RichTextJSON-root"><p class="_1qeIAgB0cPwnLhDF9XSiJM">He need to taste it.</p></div>`

```
comment = post.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "RichTextJSON-root").text
```